# How to use multiple authentication schemes in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app and in Azure Portal I have configured Easy Auth -> Azure Active Directory.

The requirement is, that the API must support both AAD and some custom JWT Authentication, so that the consumer can Authenticate either using AAD or JWT.

How can I support multiple authentication mechanisms in Azure Functions?

Comment: I think you won't be able to use Easy Auth in that case unless you can allow unauthenticated calls through to your app.

Answer (score 0):

As Easy Auth is actually an IIS module, I believe you'll need to receive the token in your Azure Function and programatically validate against the support providers.

Comment: That's clear to me, but how? Any sample? Functions does not have middleware like asp.net core

Comment: what if you implement this part using aspnet core and host it on Azure Container Instances, then forward it to Azure Functions (or not in case not authorized)

Comment: You can validate jwt tokens directly (assuming that’s what you’re using) and convert it to a ClaimsPrincipal - I have an example aad provider that works in az functions. If you’d like I could post it in a GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way you would do it in an ASP.NET Core application by using this package: [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize) for Functions V3+, or [DarkLoop.Azure.WebJobs.Authorize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.WebJobs.Authorize) for Functions V2.
You can read this [blog post](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3) for more information.
It will allow you to configure as many authentication protocols for authentication with the power of policies for every individual HTTP triggered function.